# Downgrade MVC project from Framework 4.5 to 4.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there a defined way of downgrading a solution to a lower version of the .net Framework.

Comment: Follow this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to target .NET Framework 4.0 in your solution first.

Right click on your project-> Properties->Application panel. You should see it there. After setting your target framework you have to compile and address all possible framework specific scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual studio you should [set the target to be Framework 4.0 (msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx). And then fixup the errors for any code manually that relies on 4.5

Answer (score 1):

If you have downloaded any packages using Nuget while your project was a 4.5 project, you need to manually remove the packages and install the pages again after you have changed your project to 4

First Update the packages and this will change many of packages using the command PM> update-package

You can remove the packages using PM > `uninstall-package packageName -force`

Install the package back using PM>install-package packageName

You can check to make sure all your nuget packages are 4.0 by looking at the `packages.config` file in the root of each project.